# adding logo to email using php mail function

Tags: php

Hi I would like to be able to attach my logo every message sent out to other users or to myself. So for example when you get an email from ebay, they send you a css formatted email that includes their email. I have tried including the direct image path to my logo, and even storing part of the image path to a variable. Both methods just echoed out the alt when the email was sent. Finally how would I format the email so it shows up well on mobile apps too? (this is just really a bonus question I thought I would ask). My php code is below

```
    $subject = 'A user is contacting you about your ad titled: '.$_GET['title'];
               $to = $currUser->getEmailById($currAd->getUserIdByAdId($_GET['id']));
               $headers  = "From: $email\r\n"; 
               $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
               $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
               $fullMessage = 
                       "<html style=\"height: 100%;\">
                         <body style=\"height: 100%;\">
                            <div style=\"min-height: 100%;height: auto !important;height: 100%;margin: 0 auto -63px;\">
                            <div style=\"min-height: 20px;padding: 19px;margin-bottom: 20px;background-color: #f5f5f5;border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;-webkit-border-radius: 4px;-moz-border-radius: 4px;border-radius: 4px;-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);width: 100%;\"><center>$defaultPath</center></div>
                            <div class=\"visitorMessage\">
                                <table style=\"width: 100%;\">
                                    <tr><th style=\"font-size: 17.5px;text-align:center;\">The following is a message from: $email</th></tr>
                                    <tr><td style=\"border:3px solid #000;text-align:center;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px;padding:10px;\">$message</td></tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div style=\"min-height:30px;width: 100%;\"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div style=\"margin-left: -20px;margin-right: -20px;padding-left: 20px;padding-right: 20px;min-height: 30px;color: #3C2C02;background: #E99A31;padding: 17px 0 18px 0;border-top: 1px solid #BC4E0F; text-align:center;width: 100%;\">
                                Don't forget to give us feedback on this buyer by clicking below!<br/>
                                <a style=\"display: inline-block;*display: inline;padding: 4px 12px;margin-bottom: 0;*margin-left: .3em;font-size: 14px;line-height: 20px;color: #333333;text-align: center;text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);vertical-align: middle;cursor: pointer;background-color: #f5f5f5;
  *background-color: #e6e6e6;background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, ffffff), to(#e6e6e6));background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);background-repeat: repeat-x;border: 1px solid #cccccc;*border: 0;border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;-webkit-border-radius: 4px;-moz-border-radius: 4px;border-radius: 4px;filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6', GradientType=0);filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);*zoom: 1;-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);text-decoration:none;\" href=\"www.scoopclassifieds.com/userFeeback.php?email=$email\">Feedback on $email</a><br/>
          <a style=\"font-sise:10px;text-align:center;\" href=\"www.scoopclassifieds.com\">scoopclassifeds.com</a>
                            </div>
                         </body>
                       </html>";
               mail($to,$subject,$fullMessage,$headers);
```

the code for default path is

```
$defaultPath = '<img src="/images/scoop3.png" alt="defaultImage" />';
```

and I had it one as

```
$defaultPath = '<img src="slir/w300-h200-q60//images/scoop3.png" alt="defaultImage" />';
```

Comment: much easier to stop using mail() and use phpmailer or swiftmail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it the way you're attempting, you need to specify the full url to the image, for example

```
<img src="http://example.com/images/scoop3.png" alt="defaultImage" />
```

The reason being the URL you use in your example is relative, meaning it makes sense (and points to the correct location of the image) in the file you're calling it from, but not from anywhere else.

Comment: Or you have to add the logo as an attachment and use its content id as the url.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. are there any security issues with this method? seems to me that there might be some

Comment: I can't think of any for you, email programs see attachments and externally sourced elements to an email as potential security risks though, which is why you often have to enable, or opt to view images in an email as they're disabled by default. An example security threat is including malicious code.

Comment: by default, no email client will show the images with out user interaction

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to put the image as an base64.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

The "advantage" is your picture hasn't to be available on the server all the time. So you can change the path and the user can still see the image in the email.